# How to use shared memory between service and User Interface App in c#?

Tags: c#, memory, semaphore, shared

If I write following in service:

```
mmfKernel = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("Global\\myMMF", 1024);
```

and following in user app:

```
MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("Global\\myMMF");
```

I get access denial to global mmf. How to grant access rights to mmfKernel to everyone with all possible rights?

But the other way round, 
following in user app after I acquire SeCreateGlobalPrivilege:

```
mmfKernel = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("Global\\myMMF", 1024);
```

and following in service:

```
MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("Global\\myMMF");
```

I get path access denial while creating mmfKernel even though I have already SeCreateGlobalPrivilege. 
How to create it as normal user but not admin?

Comment: I don't know why you prefer to use `MemoryMappedFile`s to cross application communication. I would suggest WCF and NamedPipe Bindigs for that need.

Comment: What do you mean Ring 1 and Ring 3? If you refer to the CPU protection rings, you *can't* have processes crossing the boundary, that's the whole point. And `BinaryFormatter` is an extremely dangerous class that's often used for attacks, because it will deserialize *anything*, including missing types. You shouldn't be using it at all, much less from a protected ring

Answer (score 3):

If they run under different user accounts, and you think memory mapped files is a good IPC for your use case, you should use another CreateNew version, which accepts MemoryMappedFileSecurity argument with the permissions.

Here’s how to creates an access control list which gives full control permission to everyone:

```
var sid = new SecurityIdentifier( WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null );
var ace = new AccessRule<MemoryMappedFileRights>( sid,
                            MemoryMappedFileRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow );
var acl = new MemoryMappedFileSecurity();
acl.AddAccessRule( ace );
```

Then pass that `acl` object to `MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew` method.

Consider which permissions you actually need. If your desktop process only needs read access to the shared file, change the access rule accordingly. Also it’s a good idea to use more specific trustee instead of everyone, maybe AuthenticatedUserSid (=“Authenticated users”) in place of WorldSid (=“Everyone”), maybe a specific user account or security group.